# Android TableLayout row height or column stretch not working

Tags: android, row, android-tablelayout, stretch

I'm having a problem with TableLayout row height.
If

```
android:stretchColumns="1"
```

the result is 
[image]

as you can see the text from the last row it's cut

if I don't specify `stretchColumns` the result is:
[image]

the text it's now showing but the table (black) gets extremely big without content.

Here's the code:

```
<TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/my_table"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:stretchColumns="*"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
```

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_table_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:weightSum="6" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/column_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.9"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" >   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

I'm populating the rows and adding to the table programmatically.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Check this out http://android-pro.blogspot.in/2010/02/table-layout.html and also http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/ Then tell me if this was helpful.

Comment: This is good one: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/

Comment: Well, those links have very useful information but in this case didn't help :/

Comment: can you post your xml code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate this type of solutions but oh well...
Instead of TableLayout I switch it to LinearLayout (both Table and Row) but the problem was the same. The difference is that with LinearLayout I just added one "empty row" and I achieve the goal. Tried the same approach with TableLayout and Rows but with no luck.

***@Francisco Corrales Morales***

```
myLinearLayoutTable.addView((LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, myLinearLayoutTable, false));
```

Comment: Just simply add a new view to the table. Added the code in the response ;)